# Running a python script with arguments that contain space from another python script

Tags: python, arguments

I am trying to run a python script from another python script but i am getting blocked because there is a space in the passed argument. The script I am trying to run is ran from the command terminal with the name and the arguments as such

```
>>>Duplicate_Checki.py "Google Control Center" "7.5 Hardening"
```

In the script which i try to call the first script the code looks like this:

```
def run_duplicate_check(self):
    os.system("python Duplicate_Checki.py Google Control Center 7.5 Hardening")
```

I get the following error

```
Duplicate_Checki.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Center 7.5 Hardening
```

Also tried
    `os.system("python Duplicate_Checki.py {} {}".format("Google Control Center" ,"7.5 Hardening"))` with the same error

I have also tried

```
os.system(python Duplicate_Checki.py "Google Control Center" "7.5 Hardening")
```

but i get invalid syntax

Comment: You'll need to escape the spaces: `os.system('python Duplicate_Checki.py "Google\ Control\ Center 7.5\ Hardening"')`

Comment: Look at `subprocess.run`. It doesn't do any splitting on spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**script.py**:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    print(args[0])
    print(args[1])
```

**runner.py**:

```
from subprocess import call

call(["python3", "script.py", "Google Control Center", "7.5 Hardening"])
```

Execution `python3 runner.py`, output:

```
Google Control Center
7.5 Hardening
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

#subprocess.run, #subprocess.check_output, #subprocess.call

Comment: I'am running the version Python 2.7, so i used `call(["Duplicate_Checki.py", "Google Control Center", "7.5 Hardening"], shell = True)`